# Reloading of page after ajax call success gives error in safari and IE browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have used ajax call to Insert data. And in success event of ajax call , i want to reload the page,so i have coded in ajax call as :

```
 myfunction: function (url, form) {

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: window.location.reload(true),
        complete: this.resetLoadWaiting,
        error: "Failer Message."
    });
},
```

This will properly work on mozila firefox and google-crome , but not working on IE for all version  and also on safari browser, it will give Failer Message, as in error section of ajax call.
So what can i do in success event ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I used `document.location.reload()` in my success event and works on all the browsers.

Comment: document.location.reload(true)